# Nested attributes for has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, nested-attributes, has-many

My models are

```
class History < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :projects_lkp
  has_many :pictures
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :pictures
end

class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :history
  validates_presence_of :pics
end
```

`history/new.html.erb`

```
<%= form_for(:history, :url => {:action => 'create'}) do |d| %>
  <%= render(:partial =>"form",:locals => {:d => d}) %>
<% end %>
```

`history/_form.html.erb`

```
<%= d.fields_for :pictures do |dd| %>   
  <div class="row form-group"></div>
    <div><class='col-md-5 form-label'>Photo</div>
    <%= dd.file_field :pic, multiple: true, :class => 'col-md-15' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

`history_controller`

```
def create
  @history = History.new(history_params)
  @history.projects_lkp_id = params[:projects_lkps_id]
  respond_to do |format|
    if @history.save
      format.html{ redirect_to histories_path(id: @history.id), notice:"History added" }
    else
      @history = History.where(item: @history.item).all
      format.html { render 'index' }
    end
  end
end

def history_params
  params.require(:history).permit(:history,:date,:pic)
end
```

But when I tried to submit form, it says that **unpermitted parameter :pictures**

Parameter passing is:

```
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"xE8d/mD1pXh/2AIKrZlRoL552iEBVZ7jkzLJB1kNZyE=", "history"=>{"history"=>" jhafjkaalkds", "date"=>"20/10/2014", "pictures"=>{"pic"=>[#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x0000000143d1f8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20150910-2753-1ml2hmf>, @original_filename="Firefox_wallpaper.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"history[pictures][pic][]\"; filename=\"Firefox_wallpaper.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">]}}, "projects_lkps_id"=>"", "commit"=>"Submit"}
```

Unpermitted parameters: pictures

*Here the :pic is the attachment field created by using paperclip gem*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer for that :)

**history controller**

```
 def new
    @histories = History.new
   @histories.pictures.build
 end
```

**history/new**

```
      <%= form_for(@histories, :url => {:action => 'create'}, html: {multipart:true})  do |d| %>
      <%= render(:partial =>"form",:locals => {:d => d}) %>
      <% end %>
```

it works :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def history_params
  params.require(:history).permit(:history, :date, pictures_attributes: [:pic])
end
```

One more problem I can see is with your form. It should be:

```
<%= form_for(:history, :url => {:action => 'create'}, multipart: true) do |d| %>
  <%= render(:partial =>"form",:locals => {:d => d}) %>
  <%= d.fields_for :pictures do |dd| %>   
    <div class="row form-group"></div>
    <div><class='col-md-5 form-label'>Photo</div>
      <%= dd.file_field :pic, multiple: true, :class => 'col-md-15' %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Parameters should be in the form:

```
"history" => { ... , "photos_attributes" => { "0" => { ... } } }
```

Comment: @MenporulPoriyalar there seems to be a problem with your form too. Please see my updated answer

Comment: i think that the problem u see it in a form is  '<% end %>' i think. but thats my fault i keep ' <%= form_for(:history, :url => {:action => 'create'}) do |d| %>
  <%= render(:partial =>"form",:locals => {:d => d}) %>
<% end %>'  is in history/new.html.erb i forget to notify that sry.

Comment: Your params also looks strange, they should contain `photos_attributes` and they don't. Can you once again review your "form_for code"?

Comment: Yes, thats my problem. now see me updated question. so u may get some clear view. @dimakura

Comment: You also miss `multipart: true` option. see here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#uploading-files

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89243/discussion-between-menporul-poriyalar-and-dimakura).